# Android - Hold Activity During Animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I want to create an animation transition in Android from one Activity to the next. But during the animation, there is a short blackout of a black background then displaying the animation of the next Activity I want to display.

**I want hold the first Activity intact so the second Activity will animate and overlap the first Activity.** How can I achieve this behaviour?

Here are my two current animation xml files, which aren't doing what i want to achieve:

*hold.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:zAdjustment="bottom" />

</set>
```

*enter.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="90%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:zAdjustment="top" />

</set>
```

My Java-Code:

```
starter.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter,
                R.anim.hold);
```

Thank you in advance,
Pat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The default animation to transition from Activty A to Activity B is device depended. If the screen turns black for a short while that is because your device implements it that way... you can however override the animation the theme of your app uses to apply your custom animation to transition between activities.

Comment: please supply any code or example of how to override the theme transition animation (and not the activity)

Answer (score 13):

**Enter activity animation**

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, AnimaitonActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_up_from_bottom, R.anim.hold);
```

**Exit activity animation**

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.hold, R.anim.push_out_to_bottom);
```

**pull_up_from_bottom.xml**

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

**push_out_to_bottom.xml**

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

**hold.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
</set>
```